# HTML Tag Cloud creation using Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tag-cloud

Is there a library which can take a python dict with word freq = { 'abc' : 25, .... } 
and convert this into a html based Tag Cloud?

Comment: (I hope this is just an intellectual exercize and you're not really implementing a tag cloud.  Let that useless gimmick *die*, already.)

Answer (score 3):

There a numerous examples for this on the web, e.g. here:

- http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/04/building-tag-cloud-with-python.html
- http://snipplr.com/view/8875/tag-cloud/
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cs.tags/0.1.1
- [and more ...](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+tag+cloud)